Google Authentication via firebase
I am building an IOS and Android app and authenticating Google sign-in with Firebase. I am also using Google Cloud Console to automatically create client IDs by firebase. However, I am facing an issue when I click sign in with Google.
What I've tried:
I checked my clients IDs to ensure they are matching well in my project.
I manually added a URL in the "Authorized Urls" field in google console
Tried to change the proxy from true to false and vise versa.
I cant seem to understand what this error means.
Here are error details:

Access blocked: Authorization Error
You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.
You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules.
Learn more about this error:
If you are a developer of Grup Lnch, see error details.
Error 400: invalid_request
Error 400: invalid_request
Request details: redirect_uri=exp://216.14.174.216:8081 flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

